# Count number of li's in a ul and assign class

Tags: javascript, jquery, counting

I have woocommerce sub-categories that dynamically display on the archive page. I need to be able to count how many are in that list and add a class to the ul based on the number. My plan was to use the new class and then use nth-child() in my css for styles. So if there are 11 list items, add product11 to the ul. If there are 5 list items, add product5 to the ul.

I've tried several different versions of jquery counting code I found on the web.

```
$('.site-main .subcategories ul.products.columns-3').each(function(index){

if(index=2)$(this).addClass("products2");
else if(index=3)$(this).addClass("products3");
else if(index=5)$(this).addClass("products5");
else if(index=6)$(this).addClass("products6");
 else if(index=7)$(this).addClass("products7");
else if(index=9)$(this).addClass("products9");
else(index=11)$(this).addClass("products11");

})
```

The result I got was that it only added the first class on products2.

Comment: If you have 5 items do you want to addclass 1,2,3,4,5 to each item or add class 5 to all 5 items? By the way in javascript (and in almost all modern programming languages) you use == for comparison. If (index==2){...}

Comment: The answer posted is a better way to go about it, however, just so you're aware of why this method doesn't work - as @NawedKhan pointed out, you have to use `==` to compare values (otherwise you're just saying `if the assignment of 2 to the variable index is successful` - which it always will be). The other issue is the final `else` includes a condition; it should either be `else if(index == 11) { ... }` or simply `else { ... }`. The answer's definitely easier, though, as it's just one line and appends the index to the class name without need for comparison.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to count the items. Just add the index ind the class name:

```
$('.site-main .subcategories ul.products.columns-3').each( function(index){
    $(this).addClass("products" + index);
})
```

**EDIT:**

I read the question again, and I think he wants to add a class depending on the total of `li` elements in `ul`. Try this code:

```
$('.site-main .subcategories ul.products.columns-3').each( function(){
    $(this).addClass('products' + $('ul.products li').length);
})
```

Comment: I think we're close...it returned:
<ul class="products columns-3 products0">

Comment: That's because index is zero-based. If you want the first one to start at 1 then add a +1 offset.

Comment: This is what I'm trying to achieve (since it has 3 li's): `<ul class="products columns-3 products3">
<li class="product-category product">Desserts and Treats</li>
<li class="product-category product">Vegetables</li>
<li class="product-category product">Meats</li>
</ul>
`

Comment: Please add your HTML code to the question. Will make it easier to understand the problem.

Comment: You can reduce it to just one line: `$('.site-main .subcategories ul.products.columns-3 li').addClass('products' + $('ul.products li').length);`